# Porting Lua to Python

Tags: python, lua, porting

Lua

```
values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
inSack = {}
total  = 0;
function knapsack(i, weight)
        if weight == 0 then
                print("Success The following combination is in the knapsack:");
                for i = 1, #inSack do
                        total = total + inSack[i];
                        print(inSack[i]);
                end
                print("Totaling to Input of: "..total)
                return
        elseif i <= 0 then
                print("Sorry your weight combination, is not possible with the current values ");
                return;
        end
        if values[i] > weight then
                return knapsack(i-1, weight);
        else 
                inSack[#inSack + 1] = values[i];
                return knapsack(i-1, weight - values[i]);
        end

end
-- Waits for user input to terminal
local number = io.read()
knapsack(#values, tonumber(number));
```

My Python code

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
inSack = []
total = 0

def knapsack(i,weight):
    if weight == 0:
        print("success: ")
        for i in inSack:
            total = total +inSack[i]
            print(inSack[i])
        print("totaling to input of: "+total)
        return
    elif i<= 0:
        print("didn't work yo")
        return
    if values[i] > weight:
        return knapsack(i-1, weight)
    else:
        inSack[inSack+1] = values[i]
        return knapsack(i-1, weight - values[i])

number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
knapsack(values, number)
```

I'm getting errors with the `if values[i] > weight` statement that i ported to python.  What is the mistake I'm making?

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lua.py", line 23, in <module>
    knapsack(values, number)
  File "lua.py", line 16, in knapsack
    if values[i] > weight:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Comment: `inSack[inSack+1] = values[i]`
Adding 1 to `inSack` which supposed to be a list?
Maybe `inSack.append(values[i])` instead? :) Also `for i in inSack:` iterates throught inSack elements. Not it's indices. `for index, element in inSack:` instead.

Comment: Considering `i` is a list, then this comparison makes no sense :`i <= 0`. (Note that in the loop `for i in inSack:`, you've actually masked the original item passed to `i`)

Comment: Stop trying to use Lua tables as Python lists...They are sooo different. :P

Comment: In python to sum a list you can simply do `sum(inSack)`.

Comment: The traceback you copy paste is probably missing the last line: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`.

Comment: @damienfrancois added the TypeError

Comment: When I read the title, I was wondering why anybody would want to port his lua errors to python errors.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Not my code, I got it from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Lua)

Comment: @user2758113 Nothing wrong with your code. I just misread the title.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are missing a `len()` at the end ; the Python equivalent of

```
knapsack(#values, tonumber(number));
```

would be

```
knapsack(len(values), number)
```